# ¿Cómo hacer un código de un movimiento en diagonal en Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Estoy comenzando a programar y quiero hacer un juego sencillo para mejorar mi portafolio. He creado un juego con un grid 7x7, donde dos jugadores se turnan sustituyendo los "0" por "X" de colores distintos para cada jugador (rojo y azul). Cada jugador elimina un cero o hasta un máximo de tres ceros (en cada casilla hay un cero). Se permiten movimientos en horizontal, vertical y diagonal, sin embargo es con éste último que tengo muchos problemas. En vez de ser una pendiente ("/"), el resultado es más como una "L". Me podrían ayudar por favor, se los agradecería muchísimo.

```
// Add event listeners
    const cells = document.querySelectorAll('.playable');
    cells.forEach(cell => {
        cell.addEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseDown);
        cell.addEventListener('touchstart', handleMouseDown);
    });

    function handleMouseDown(event) {
        const selectedCell = event.target;
    
        // Verifica si hay más de tres celdas marcadas, que es lo permitido.
        if (selectedCell.textContent === '0' && moveCount < 3) {
            // Marca la celda seleccionada con la marca del jugador actual
            selectedCell.textContent = 'X';
            selectedCell.classList.add(playerMarks[currentPlayer]);
            moveCount++;
    
            // Agrega event listeners para los eventos de movimiento del ratón
            document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
            document.addEventListener('touchmove', handleMouseMove);
    
            // Agrega event listeners para los eventos de liberación del ratón
            document.addEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
            document.addEventListener('touchend', handleMouseUp);
    
            // Deshabilita el desplazamiento de la página durante el arrastre
            document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
        }
    }
    
    function handleMouseMove(event) {
        const selectedCell = document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);
    
        // Verifica si la celda es jugable y no está marcada, y si el contador de movimientos es menor que 3
        if (selectedCell.classList.contains('playable') && selectedCell.textContent === '0' && moveCount < 3) {
            // Marca la celda seleccionada con la marca del jugador actual
            selectedCell.textContent = 'X';
            selectedCell.classList.add(playerMarks[currentPlayer]);
            moveCount++;
        } else if (!selectedCell.classList.contains('playable') && !selectedCell.classList.contains(playerMarks[1 - currentPlayer])) {
            // Detiene el movimiento adicional si se encuentra una celda no jugable o la marca del oponente
            document.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
            document.removeEventListener("touchmove", handleMouseMove);
        }
    }
    
    function handleMouseUp() {
        // Elimina event listeners para los eventos de movimiento del ratón
        document.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
        // Elimina event listeners para los eventos de liberación del ratón
        document.removeEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
        // Elimina event listeners para los eventos de movimiento táctil
        document.removeEventListener("touchmove", handleMouseMove);
        // Elimina event listeners para los eventos de liberación táctil
        document.removeEventListener("touchend", handleMouseUp);
    
        // Cambia al jugador actual
        currentPlayer = currentPlayer === 0 ? 1 : 0;
    
        // Restablece el contador de movimientos
        moveCount = 0;
    
        // Restaura el desplazamiento de la página
        document.body.style.overflow = 'auto';
    }
```

Comment: Podrías añadir el código `html` asociado al código de Javascript que muestras en tu pregunta?

Comment: Disculpa, pero no sé cómo hacer para enviarte el resto del código, lo he intentado pero soy nuevo y no sé cómo. Incluso intenté modificar la pregunta, para enviar el código completo.

Comment: Elías debes [edit] la pregunta, y buscar el icono `<>` ahí colocas el código. Mas información en -> https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3292/qu%c3%a9-es-stack-snippet

Comment: Hola elias te recomiendo hacer el [tour]